Why does Shannon-Fano-Elias coding use the interval midpoint specifically?
I am currently doing a course on data compression at university, where I am studying Shannon-Fano-Elias coding and Arithmetic coding at the moment. As explained in Thomas and Covers book "Elements of Information Theory", Shannon-Fano-Elias coding makes use of the midpoint of the probability interval to uniquely identify the corresponding alphabet symbol. Similarly, in arithmetic coding, an interval is determined for a considered message and then in order to uniquely specify this interval, the truncated interval midpoint is used.
My question is: Why specifically use the interval midpoint in both methods? Is there a mathematical reasoning for this?
I could not come up with one of my own and also have not found any information on this in the aforementioned book or online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
